# Launching app in hidden window using Remote Desktop Connection (Win 10)

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

How can I see the window of an app that shows on the second screen of my multi-monitor set-up when I remote in from another computer?

For example:

...on my laptop:
cmd: mstsc /span
rdc display configuration: Full Screen + Use all of my monitors for the remote session

...on the remote computer:
Open GitGUI or FileZilla for example.
Task bar shows application open.
The hover preview shows the app is open.
I can't see the app window on my screen (can't interact with it).

Nothing I do brings the app to a window I can use.

Anyone else come across this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Using the Windows key plus the right/left arrows, I can move windows from desktop to desktop.